# What does "...crickity" mean?

Tags: meaning

Good morning guys,

What does **crickity** mean? I was reading a basic English book for my little song and the phrase "crickity" showed up. I looked it up in the dictionary but could not find it. You can find this part of the book following [this link](https://www.google.com.ni/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRsLGIq-7NAhXKFR4KHUODAPcQjRwIBw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fus%2Fbook%2Fsplat-cat-duck-no-quack%2Fid438353704%3Fmt%3D11&psig=AFQjCNG9g1S2OEEFAXl-9mpY9PnIL5GaTw&ust=1468427015962042).

Thanks

Comment: We really need the full context for this! Could you give us the verse that _crickity_ occurs in?

Comment: It is related to [creak](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=creak). It is often used as "old and crickity" to refer to old people with noisy joints when they move. Or a similar cracking noise of some object. Couldn't believe *crickity* isn't in regular dictionaries, though.

Comment: Thanks AlanCarmack; you were the closest one with your instructions about how to find this phrase.

Comment: Well, is the word you are asking about **crickity** (with an R) or **clickity** (with an L)?

Comment: You should have checked the spelling of the word twice before asking about it.

Comment: [Splat the Cat and the Duck with No Quack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMNlvXTI0JM). Where did you meet "crickety" there?

Comment: @Glorfindel Please STOP taking out the personal comments, until at least the OP has responded to the answer, edited it with the correct word, or a day has gone by. SE does not need [phatic](https://www.google.com/search?q=phatic+define) comments to be left in, but we also don't have to strip them out, dehumanizing the question, as fast as you want to.

Comment: @AlanCarmack sadly, only [3% of the SE community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/295232) agrees with you. Greetings and thanks are noise, the sooner people learn not to post them, the better. Writing clear and concise posts is the way to show respect to the other members of the community.

Comment: @CesarCastilloAlfaro If you are asking about **clickity** and not **crickity** please edit your question.

Comment: "Crickety" is a proper word and can be found in unabridged dictionaries. User3169's comment is pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question says we can find "this part of the book" in the link your provide. I don't find **crickity**, so I am answering about the word **clickity**, which is what I think you are referring to.

The opening line of the story includes the compound word **clickity clack**.

> Splat's bike went clickity clack.

[image]

The word is usually spelt '[clickety-clack](https://www.google.com/search?q=clickety+clack)'. But since the word refers to a *sound*, there are variations in spelling. [Dictionary dot com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/clickety-clack) provides this definition:

> [the] rhythmic, swiftly paced succession of alternating clicks and clacks, as the sound produced by the wheels of a train moving over tracks

In the story, *clickity clack* refers to the sound of the bike's wheels as the bike goes over "the bumpy track." The word can also refer to the sound of one or more typewriters.

The word can be spelled different ways, including 'clickety clack' and 'clickity click'. All these are examples of [onomatopoeia](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/words-that-sound-like-the-thing-they-describe), or a word that sounds like what it means. A computer mouse button and the shutter of an SLR camera make a *click* when you press them. Other examples of words that sound like what they mean from the opening pages of the story include *Splat*, *whack*, *smack* and, later, *quack*.

Video of the story being read to a kid: [Splat the Cat and the Duck with No Quack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMNlvXTI0JM).

Another way to get a clickity click noise from bike wheels is to attach playing cards to the bike frame so that the spokes of the wheels hit the card. But this makes a much faster *clickity noise* then does the sound of the wheels on a bumpy track. For example, see this [youtube video](https://youtu.be/krPQ1PMM00Y). This is not what is happening in the story, but it is something  that kids do.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: I had my answer about "crickety", not "crickity" posted before the link to the source appeared, and it became obvious that the PO doesn't care a bit about the spelling. You're a great, kind hearted person, Alan, I swear.